# Deploy war file in jboss server 7.0

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

When I try to deploy war file in jboss server 7.0, it showing below error. Please advise.

Exception log:

```
    2019-09-22 18:28:22,582 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final-redhat-1
    2019-09-22 18:28:24,904 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final-redhat-1
    2019-09-22 18:28:25,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1) starting  
    2019-09-22 18:29:14,879 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0058: Additional resource root /C:/jboss-eap-7.0.0/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/content/bancaws.war/WEB-INF/lib/bcpg-jdk15on-1.58.jar added via jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist
    2019-09-22 18:29:14,880 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0058: Additional resource root /C:/jboss-eap-7.0.0/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/content/bancaws.war/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.58.jar added via jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist
    2019-09-22 18:29:14,884 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0058: Additional resource root /C:/jboss-eap-7.0.0/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/content/bancaws.war/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar added via jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist
    2019-09-22 18:29:14,885 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0058: Additional resource root /C:/jboss-eap-7.0.0/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/content/bancaws.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar added via jboss-deployment-structure.xml does not exist
    2019-09-22 18:29:14,917 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry oraclepki.jar in /C:/jboss-eap-7.0.0/jboss-eap-7.0/bin/content/bancaws.war/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc8-18.3.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
    2019-09-22 18:29:20,507 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.bancaws.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.bancaws.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.bancaws.war:main
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.deploy.api:main
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1092)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1448)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1476)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
        ... 5 more

    2019-09-22 18:29:20,520 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "bancaws.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.bancaws.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.bancaws.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.bancaws.war:main
        Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.deploy.api:main"}}
    2019-09-22 18:29:20,554 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "bancaws.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
    {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.bancaws.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.bancaws.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.bancaws.war:main
        Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.deploy.api:main"}}
    2019-09-22 18:29:22,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment bancaws.war (runtime-name: bancaws.war) in 1656ms
    2019-09-22 18:29:22,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
          service jboss.module.service."deployment.bancaws.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."bancaws.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE] 
    WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.module.service."deployment.bancaws.war".main
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: You should put the whole log but it may be related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590215/error-processing-condition-on-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-context-pro?rq=1

Comment: I have posted the stack trace. Tq

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the jboss with standalone-full.xml using below command.

Standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml

Answer (score 0):

The module name "javax.enterprise.deploy.api:main" is not correct it should be like "javax.enterprise.api.main" or make sure the module is present in $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/javax/enterprise/deploy/api if you have configured any custom module.