# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have run springboot application in a docker container with tomcat 9.0.58 and open jdk 11. But when i start the container i am getting as exception as below:

```
*service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word] not found - trying original name [logging.exception-conversion-word]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.exception-conversion-word]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.exception-conversion-word] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word] not found - trying original name [logging.exception-conversion-word]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.exception-conversion-word]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.exception-conversion-word] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.console] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.console]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.console].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.console] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.console].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.console] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.console]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.console].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.console] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.console].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.console] not found - trying original name [logging.charset.console]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.charset.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.console].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.charset.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.charset.console] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.charset.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.console].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.console] not found - trying original name [logging.charset.console]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.charset.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.console].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.charset.console]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.charset.console] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.charset.console] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.console].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.dateformat]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.dateformat] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.dateformat]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.dateformat] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.dateformat].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.dateformat]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.dateformat] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.dateformat] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.dateformat].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.dateformat]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.dateformat] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.dateformat]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.dateformat] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.dateformat].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.dateformat]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.dateformat] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.dateformat] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.dateformat].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.file] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.file]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.file].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.file] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.file].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.file] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.file]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.file].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.file] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.file].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.file] not found - trying original name [logging.charset.file]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.charset.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.file].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.charset.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.charset.file] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.charset.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.file].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.charset.file] not found - trying original name [logging.charset.file]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.charset.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.file].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.charset.file]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.charset.file] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.charset.file] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.charset.file].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.level]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.level] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.level]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.level] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.level].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.level]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.level] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.level] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.level].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.level]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.pattern.level] not found - trying original name [logging.pattern.level]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.pattern.level] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.level].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.pattern.level]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.pattern.level] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.pattern.level] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.pattern.level].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.log4j2.config.override]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.log4j2.config.override] not found - trying original name [logging.log4j2.config.override]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.log4j2.config.override] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.log4j2.config.override].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.log4j2.config.override]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.log4j2.config.override] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.log4j2.config.override] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.log4j2.config.override].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.log4j2.config.override]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.log4j2.config.override] not found - trying original name [logging.log4j2.config.override]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.log4j2.config.override] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.log4j2.config.override].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.log4j2.config.override]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.log4j2.config.override] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.log4j2.config.override] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.log4j2.config.override].. Returning null.
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.log4j2.config.override[0]]
service_container  | [DEBUG] Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.log4j2.config.override[0]] not found - trying original name [logging.log4j2.config.override[0]]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.log4j2.config.override[0]] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.log4j2.config.override[0]].
service_container  | [DEBUG] Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.log4j2.config.override[0]]
service_container  | [DEBUG] JNDI lookup for name [logging.log4j2.config.override[0]] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.log4j2.config.override[0]] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.log4j2.config.override[0]].. Returning null.
service_container  | 
service_container  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
service_container  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
service_container  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
service_container  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
service_container  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
service_container  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
service_container  |  :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.10)
service_container  | 
service_container  | 2023-09-01 11:51:11 ||org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version:21-INFO = HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.5.Final
service_container  | 2023-09-01 11:51:11 ||com.bose.smart.dnc.ServletInitializer:55-INFO = Starting ServletInitializer v0.0.1 using Java 11.0.14.1 on 3592fcae4721 with PID 1 (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes started by root in /usr/local/tomcat)
service_container  | 2023-09-01 11:51:11 ||com.bose.smart.dnc.ServletInitializer:637-INFO = The following 1 profile is active: "linux"
service_container  | 2023-09-01 11:51:13 ||org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:821-ERROR= Application run failed
service_container  | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:946) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  |    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476) ~[bootstrap.jar:9.0.58]
service_container  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.bose.smart.dnc.configuration.DependencyConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
service_container  |   context: ROOT
service_container  |   delegate: false
service_container  | ----------> Parent Classloader:
service_container  | java.net.URLClassLoader@2ef1e4fa
service_container  | ]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:669) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:661) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1302) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:864) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:852) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:839) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-web-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]

service_container  |    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[?:?]
service_container  |    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
service_container  |    ... 62 more
service_container  | 02-Sep-2023 15:07:25.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war] has
 finished in [9,982] ms
service_container  | 02-Sep-2023 15:07:25.022 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
service_container  | 02-Sep-2023 15:07:25.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [10068] milliseconds

*
```

I have already gone through numerous content such as :[Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590215/error-processing-condition-on-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-context-pro) ,but i am unable to understand the root process as to how i can figure out which 2 dependencies in spring boot are conflicting.

Dockerfile :

```
 FROM tomcat:9.0.58-jdk11-openjdk 
 EXPOSE 8080
 RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ 
 RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/sdnc_file/in_temp
 RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/sdnc_file/out_temp 
 RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/sdnc_file/mapping_sheet   
 COPY ./target/sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war  
 CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

Comment: What's the complete stack trace of the failure? The cause of the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` that you've shared should provide details of the processing error.

Comment: I bed your pardon , i had missed it . Now i have updated in my query

Comment: Please find docker file attached too :

`*FROM tomcat:9.0.58-jdk11-openjdk

EXPOSE 8080
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/sdnc_file/in_temp
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/sdnc_file/out_temp
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/sdnc_file/mapping_sheet


COPY ./target/sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
*`

Comment: Your Dockerfile Is not readable if you post It as a comment, you should post It by editing the question.

Comment: The exception is still truncated. There's a problem with `com.bose.smart.dnc.configuration.DependencyConfiguration` but we can't see what it is as you haven't shared the cause of the second `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: I am sorry there is too much logs and it is exceeding limitations.  Here are the logs please:

`  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.bose.smart.dnc.configuration.DependencyConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  |   context: ROOT
  |   delegate: false
  | ----------> Parent Classloader:
  | java.net.URLClassLoader@2ef1e4fa
  | ]
  |  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26];

Comment: I have removed log content name service_container as it is clouding the log content.

Comment: @Pino  :thankyou for notifying i have update it now

Comment: Post rechecking i got the resolution. There were two same name  packages (in this case [com.bose.smart.dnc.excelService]) pointing to similar code from 2 different jar files. I understood this solution while debugging from Intellij. Thankyou for your support.